# Plot scatter for classification algorithm

Tags: python, matplotlib, decision-tree, scatter

Please help me to create scatter graph for this classification algorithm. Here in y i have a column of labels( 0, 1) i want the predicted labels in two different colors for both labels.

```
X = np.array(df.iloc[: , [0, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,]].values)
y = df.iloc[: , 17].values 
dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier()
train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(X, y, train_size = 0.8, shuffle = True)
kf = KFold(n_splits = 5)
dtc=dtc.fit(train_x, train_y)
dtc_labels = dtc.predict(test_x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have access to your dataframes, but here is a minimum working example, assuming I understood right.

The point is that you have to use logical indexing for your numpy arrays during plotting. This is exemplified by the last two lines.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, KFold
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
X = np.zeros((100,2))
X[:,0] = np.array(list(range(100)))
X[:,1] = np.array(list(range(100)))
y = list([0] * 50 + [1] * 50)
dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier()
train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(X, y, train_size = 0.8, shuffle = True)
kf = KFold(n_splits = 5)
dtc=dtc.fit(train_x, train_y)
dtc_labels = dtc.predict(test_x)

plt.scatter(test_x[dtc_labels == 0,0],test_x[dtc_labels == 0,1])
plt.scatter(test_x[dtc_labels == 1,0],test_x[dtc_labels == 1,1])
```

Comment: I have total 17 columns and 1150 rows X represent 17 columns and y is 1 label column

Comment: This still should work, but you need to make a decision on which 2 columns to plot, or you need to use some form of dimensionality reduction.

Comment: Error: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1

Comment: and please explain what is y

Comment: That means that test_x is is shape n x 1. If you do print(test_x.shape) and print(len(dtc_labels)) or print(dtc_labels.shape) (if the former fails), what does it do? X, and y are place holders here for your stuff. As long as your stuff has the same dtype, but different column shape, it should work, I think.

Comment: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtEaQ.png) this is my dataset column 18 is class `` X = np.array(df.iloc[: , [12]].values)
X = np.array(df.iloc[: , [13]].values)`` and this two columns i am selecting

Comment: If you set `X = np.array(df.iloc[: , [12,13]].values)` and `y=np.array(df.iloc[: , [18]].values)`, then it should work. But you should really check the shapes and types of the objects before plotting them. It's gonna make your life easier.

Comment: (231, 1)
(231,) this is my test_x and dtc_labels shape i am getting error index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1

Comment: This makes sense, right? You should choose two columns for X, if you want to do a scatter plot. Your test_x should have two columns. So if you do the lines of codes that I mentioned in the previous comments, it should work.

Comment: what does last two scatter plot line means? i mean how it plots what is test_x[dtc_label==0,0] means

Comment: You might want to look into logical indexing if it is confusing for you: https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing

Comment: can you bit explain how`` test_x[dtc_label==0,0]`` will plot?